# Line break at dot

Tags: java

Am taking text where there is tag

i want to **Line break** each time `.` is found. e.g:

The boy is going home. `LINE BREAK`

She is returning `LINE BREAK`

can anyone give me a sample code how to do this

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stackoverflow, the purpose of this Q&A board is to answer questions people have about problems one might encounter while writing, or trying to write a code. This is not a way to ask for other developers to write code for yourself. Think of the question of a way to get an answer for you, so you can help future readers having a similar question get an answer as well. Your post is likely to be closed, and then deleted soon, so please take my comment into account next time you ask a question. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace `.` with a `.` and a line break:

```
String s = "Some.Text.With.Dots.Here.";
s = s.replace(".", String.format(".%n"));
```